# Remove all characters after any number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have text like:

```
#1 Supermarket 3454
Ubermarket 23478
Single_Token
Two Tokens
As many tokens as you like
```

And I'd like to remove the last number (when it appears) so I'm left with:

```
#1 Supermarket
Ubermarket
Single_Token
Two Tokens
As many tokens as you like
```

The data is added to regularly, so I would appreciate using an excel formula and not a mandrolic method using column splitting, or the like.

However I can't figure out how to use find to find all numbers, or substitute to only take number off the end.

edit: as people seem to neeed me to prove my accepted answer works, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does you want to do this by formula, or VBA user-defined function is safe for you?

Comment: @Akina I'd rather not dabble in VBA because it means duplicating the code in all the spreadsheets I need this in.

Comment: *it means duplicating the code in all the spreadsheets* Why? you can place it into common module - it will be available on all sheets in this workbook. You can place it into personal macro storage - it will be available in all workbooks on your workstation.

Comment: @Akina I did not know about personal macro storage

Comment: Try to start a macro recording, you will be asked about where does you want to place this macro to.

Comment: @fixer1234 the accepted answer works, I have uploaded a screenshot to prove it. Did you see JvdV's update...or did you not think that worked either?

Comment: Lets move the discussion to [meta](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13765/do-i-need-to-prove-the-accepted-answer-is-correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would there only be numbers at the very end you need to take off? Nothing like `#1 Supermarket 33 and 12345` or `#1 Supermarket 12442 12321`?

In that case you can take of the last `word` of the string using:

```
=LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))))-1)
```

[image]

Edit:

After your comments below I believe you can wrap it in an `IF` statement to check if last char is a number and if there are spaces in the string, like so:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,1)*1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")>0)),LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1),A1)
```

Comment: No, nothing except a number at the end. How does this work?

Comment: Relatively simple; through `SUBSTITUTE` we first get the number of spaces in the string (full length minus lengt when spaces are substituted out). Now we know the amount of spaces we can use that number in a second substitute as our instance number to only change the last space into a non occurent character. At last we use that character in a `FIND` to get the correct number of chars from the left. You can go through the formula yourself using formula evaluation.

Comment: Applying it to more data I have, it looks like it removes the last token, not the last number.

Comment: Hence why I asked you how your data looks. If there is a number at the end of all the string you have, then this will work as you can see at the example data I used.

Comment: Apologies, I took what you said as meaning "do you only want to take off number at the end, nothing else" which is not what you said.

Comment: So there are strings without numbers, and even single tokens? Which version of Excel have you got?

Comment: yes that is true. I think it's 2016/2017, but I will need to check later.

Comment: @Pureferret edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest the most easiest & built in method to separate Text left to the numbers is, **Text to Column** command.*

[image]

- From **Data Tab** hit *Text to Column* then pick **Fixed Width** option then **Next**.
- You get this:

[image]

- Hit the **Finish** button.

*You get this:*

[image]

Comment: This won't work as I'm constantly adding new rows of data and performing the same operation over and over will take up more time than a formula that will automatically run.

Comment: @Pureferret,, my simple suggestion is, edit the post & mention that data will be update frequently therefore you need any swift method,, also try to update sample data with as many possible values considering the change,,, since I've created this answer on the basic of information available with the post (Question) !!

Comment: This was a legitimate solution to the question as originally posed.  With the question's update and information in the comment that is missing in the question, the OP has clarified that the data is more complex than originally implied, and this won't handle it.  Under the circumstances, the downvote is a bit harsh.  Nevertheless, the answer doesn't address the question as now clarified, so it's kind of fair game.  You might want to save your rep and just delete this since it won't help anyone.  It was a good quality answer, though.

Comment: @fixer1234,, it's not the question to save rep,, answer is all around the original post,, and Edit comes into air,, just few Hrs before, with older data set, was down voted long back !!